# how to solve run time error of loaded the "DetailViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Tags: objective-c

I am beginner of iPhone here come the error of run time of

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "DetailViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

give any suggestion and source code which is apply in my code....

Comment: Check if you have connected the view outlet properly to your nib files

Comment: @user1432045 Did you connect create a xib for that View Controller? Did you link it in Interface Builder,( from File Owner to the View)

Answer (score 0):

it would be easier to help you if you could post the code of your uiviewcontroller. I guess you have some IBOutlets which aren't connected properly between your UIViewController class and the corresponding Controller on the Storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your root view of the nib file to the `view` property of the files owner (your DetailViewController).